# Windows Batch echo variable with old value

Tags: command-line, cmd

Here's a sample:

```
D:\>set var=123

D:\>set var=456 & echo %var%
123

D:\>set var=789 & echo %var%
456
```

A new value is set in *var* variable, but *echo* still displays an old value.

Anyone have a clue as to what happened? And how to get correct value?

Comment: Perhaps you are assuming that the command interpreter works from left to right? What if works from right to left?

Comment: & (syntax: command1 & command2) : Use to separate multiple commands on one command line. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then the second command. (https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/set.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When execution of a command or block of commands (commands concatenated or enclosed in parenthesis) is requested, the parser replaces all read operations on variables with the content in the variable **before** starting to execute the commands/block

In your case, the value in the variable is changed at execution time, but the value to `echo` to console was determined before the change was made. This can be tested with

```dos
set "var=abc"
set "var=123" & set var & echo %var%
```

`set var` will show you the correct value in the variable (in this command there was no variable read operation to be replaced by the parser) but `echo` will show the old value (replaced by the parser before command execution).

Inside batch files, the usual way to handle it is to use delayed expansion (`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command), that will allow you to change, where needed, the syntax to access variables from `%var%` into `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the read operation must be delayed until the command is executed.

BUT you can not enable delayed expansion from command line. Maybe it is enabled (not the default state) and you will be able to use it

```dos
set "var=abc"
set "var=123" & echo !var!
```

But as said, this is not the usual case. You will need to escape the percent signs to hide the variable from the parser and force a second parser evaluation of the line.

```dos
set "var=abc"
set "var=123" & call echo ^%var^%
```

Or you can spawn a separate `cmd` instance with delayed expansion enabled

```dos
set "var=abc"
set "var=123" & cmd /v /c"echo !var!"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to `delayedexpansion`.

The entire command is parsed, and any %var% is replaced by its then-current value.

Then the command is executed. The value is varied, but the `echo` command has had the variable replaced by the value as it was at parse-time.

You could try `set var` to display the current value, or `for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ('set var 2^>nul') do echo %%b` or even more robust, `for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ('set var 2^>nul') do if /i "%%a"=="var" echo %%b`

Where the `2^>nul` suppresses error messages should `var` not be defined. the caret (`^`) is required to tell `cmd` that the redirector is part of the command that `for` should execute.

Since `set var` will list all variables which start`var`, the last method is more robust than the former.